# passing array to controller from a button in yii2

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

when rendering array with double digit from controller to view page the array is displaying only the first single digit value

views/view1.php

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="index.php?r=followusers/follow&id=<?=   $follower1, $followed1; ?>" >Follow</a>
```

controller

```
public function actionFollow($id)
 {
    $model = Followusers::findOne($id);
               return $this->render('follow', [
            'model' => $model, 'id' => $id,
            ]);
```

views/follow.php

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
->insert('followusers', [
'follower' => $id[0],
'followed' => $id[1],
])->execute();

 Yii::$app->response->redirect(['user/view1','id' => $id[1]]);
 }
```

when the $follower1 or $followed1 is assigned with 10 its only taking 1 to the  id  on clicking the follow button
why it is occurring is there any blunder in my code
thanks in advance

Comment: Please could you explain me what mean href="index.php?r=followusers/follow&id=<?=   $follower1, $followed1; ?>"  and show me what result you obtain for this ... i like see the url generated ..

Comment: http://localhost/series/index.php?r=followusers/follow&id=210  // here $follower = 2 and $followed = 10

Answer (score 0):

i actually done mistake while passing parameters to url it should be done in this manner

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="index.php?r=followusers/follow&id=<?=  $follower1;?>&usr=<?= $followed1;?>" >Follow</a>
                        instead of above in the view1.php
```